# Bootstrap 4: Split Navbar and display in two navbar-toggler for small screen devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have created a navbar using bootstrap 4. This navbar has 10 'nav-items'. For big screens it is displayed in-line and for small screen I have used 'navbar-toggler'. This works fine. But I want to split this navbar and show in 2 navbar-toggler for small screens.

Is it possible? Also I am new to bootstrap!!

Below is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md my-navbar">
<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand"></a>    
<!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>   
<!--Navbar Links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

For small devices,
I want Link 1 and link 2 to be collapsed under toggler-1
and Link A and Link B to be collapsed toggler-2

Comment: Welcome, this is your first question. May I suggest that you edit your post and start by explaining the problem, followed by everything you have already tried to resolve it and conclude with you expectation. Keep each question focused on a single problem and provide as much information as possible to attract attract a knowledgeable user with your answer.

Comment: @nickl I have updated the post with the code. With this code the navbar is collapsed to single toggler icon for small screen. I want is to be shown as to togglers with Link-1 & Link-2 under toggler-1  and Link-A & Link-B under toggler-2

Answer (score 1):

Is this perhaps what you had in mind?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md my-navbar">
<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand"></a>    
<!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar1">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>   
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar2">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>   
<!--Navbar Links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar1">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link animated zoomIn" href="#">Link B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

We now have two collapsible nav bars `#collapsibleNavbar1` and `#collapsibleNavbar2` with two togglers to drive each of them. What I found was the 1st toggle button ends up in the middle of the menu bar but this would probably be stylable.

Comment: @nickel, Thanks. This solution worked for me. but for large screen it is showing as 2 different menus with gap in the middle. yes this could be styled with some CSS tricks. thank for the solution